# Cómo separar un texto en punto y coma (";") que no se encuentre entrecomillado

Tags: javascript, regex

Quiero analizar una gramática [antlr](/questions/tagged/antlr). Para eso, intento separar las reglas definidas, para utilizarlas más adelante. Cada regla se separa con `;`. Sin embargo, un `;` también podría aparecer como texto dentro de la regla si está entre comillas.

Suponiendo que tengo algo como lo siguiente:

```
foo : ':' | ';' | '//' | '/*' | '*/' | '/**/'
;
```

¿Qué expresión regular debería utilizar para separar las reglas por los `;` del final?

Actualmente tengo esto:

```
/[^'][\s]*;[\s]*/g
```

Pero si añado un espacio antes del `;` definido en la regla ya me hace match con esa situación. Y si quitase los `[\s]*` también haría match con situaciones no deseadas.

Tan solo necesito que la expresión regular encuentre las coincidencias de `;` que no se encuentren entrecomilladas. Y, en lo posible, también necesito separar el identificador de la regla de su definición (split de los dos puntos) para tratarlos más adelante en el programa que estoy haciendo.

Comment: Además de que estás haciendo una pregunta en inglés en un sitio en español, deberías leer https://es.stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info y cumplir con los puntos solicitados

Comment: Y, luego de eso, ¿podrías explicar por qué usarías regex si ya estás usando ANTLR?

Comment: @Mariano también necesito separar el identificador de la regla de su definición (split de los dos puntos) para tratarlos más adelante en el programa que estoy haciendo.

Comment: @Mariano se me había pasado el lenguaje de programación que uso. El resto está todo no?

Comment: No se si lo que buscas es algo asi: https://regex101.com/r/3lk9uC/1  `/([^;]*;)/gi`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La idea no es buscar hacer un split, sino que coincida con todo el texto de la regla. Para eso, buscamos excluir a las comillas de los caracteres con los que puede coincidir, y luego agregamos un subpatrón especialmente para que coincida con un conjunto de comillas.

**Expresión regular:**     <sup><sub>[(regex101)](https://regex101.com/r/5Vgsyn/1/)</sub></sup>

```
/(?:^|;)\s*([^\s;:"']+)\s*:\s*([^;:"']*(?:(?:'[^']*'|"[^"]*")[^;:"']*)*)/g
```

**Descripción:**

[image: Esquema de Debuggex.com]

- `(?:^|;)` ≝ Coincide con el inicio: el inicio del texto (`^`), o el `;` de la regla anterior.
- `\s*` ≝ Cualquier cantidad de espacios en blanco (antes del nombre).
- `([^\s;:"']+)` ≝ **Grupo 1** - El nombre de la regla.

  - `[^\s;:"']+` ≝ coincide con 1 caracter, cualquiera excepto espacios en blanco, `;`, `:`, `"`, o `'`.
    El `+` lo repite 1 o más veces, haciendo que coincida con 1 o más caracteres del nombre.
- `\s*:\s*` ≝ Separador (espacios en blanco opcionales, `:` y más espacios en blanco opcionales).
- `([^;:"']*(?:(?:'[^']*'|"[^"]*")[^;:"']*)*)` ≝ **Grupo 2** - Esta es la regla.

  - `[^;:"']*` ≝ Cualquier cantidad de caracteres que no sean `;`, `:`, `"`, ni `'`, seguidos de
  - `(?:(?:'[^']*'|"[^"]*")[^;:"']*)*` ≝ grupo sin captura, para repetir (0-infinito):

    - `(?:'[^']*'|"[^"]*")` - Un conjunto de comillas simples (`'[^']*'`) o uno de comillas dobles (`"[^"]*"`)
  - `[^;:"']*` ≝ seguido de más caracteres permitidos.

Modificador: `g` (global) para obtener todas las coincidencias, y no solo la primera.

Como se puede ver, lo importante, lo que queremos capturar está entre paréntesis. Eso es un grupo. Y cada grupo nos permite obtener el texto con el que coincidió.

Al ejecutar [RegExp.exec()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/RegExp/exec), se devuelve un array, donde el primer índice es la coincidencia global, y luego el índice 1 es el grupo 1, el 2 es el 2, y así sucesivamente.

> Nota:
>
> El bucle interno, donde se coincide con la regla, manejando las excepciones de las comillas:
>
> ```
> [^;:"']*(?:(?:'[^']*'|"[^"]*")[^;:"']*)*
> ```
>
> sigue la técnica llamada *unrolling the loop*, que es la forma más eficiente 
>   de coincidir con un patrón que tiene excepciones. En este caso, texto que no 
>   es un `;`, excepto que esté entre comillas.
>
> La forma general se puede resumir como:
>
> ```
> normal*   ( excepción  normal* )*
> ```
>
> Más información sobre *unrolling the loop* en:
>   http://www.softec.lu/site/RegularExpressions/UnrollingTheLoop

**Código:**

```js
var inpTexto     = document.getElementById('texto'),
    inpResultado = document.getElementById('resultado');

inpTexto.addEventListener('input', mostrarCoincidencias);



function mostrarCoincidencias(evt) {
  var texto = (evt ? evt.target : inpTexto).value,
      regex = /(?:^|;)\s*([^\s;:"']+)\s*:\s*([^;:"']*(?:(?:'[^']*'|"[^"]*")[^;:"']*)*)/g,
      m,
      resultado = '';

  //Ejecutamos el regex en el texto, coincidencia por coincidencia:
  while (m = regex.exec(texto)) {
    //Obtenemos la captura del grupo 1 y grupo 2
    var nombre = m[1],
        regla  = m[2];

    //Agregamos al resultado
    resultado += "Nombre:\t" + nombre
              + "\nRegla:\t" + regla
              + "\n";
  }
  //Mostramos en la página
  inpResultado.innerText = resultado;
}

//init
mostrarCoincidencias();
```

```css
#texto {
  width: 100%;
  height: 6em;
}
```

```html
<textarea id="texto">foo : ':' | ';' | '//' | '/*' | '*/' | '/**/'
;
regla2:";"|':';</textarea>
<pre id="resultado" />
```